# Invalid hooks call on top functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use Hooks in my 16.14.00 react App. But every time I use one, I get the invalid hooks warning :"https://fr.reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html".[image: invalid hooks call screen]

I checked:

- My call is not in any conditional block
- The 'useState' call is at the top of the function.
- I only have one react version.

What is weird about that is that I CAN use Hooks in other components, it is like React does not accept hooks on my App() functional component.

Here is my code.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Cursor from './cursor';
import CollapsiblePanel from './collapsiblePanel';
import MainPanel from './mainPanel';
import SideBar from './sidebar/sidebar';


export default function App() {
  
    const [cursorGlowing, setCursorGlowing] = useState(false);
    
    const glowCursor = (bool) => {
      setCursorGlowing(false);
    }

    return (
      <div className="app">
        <SideBar glowCursor={() => glowCursor}/>
        <Cursor glow={cursorGlowing}/>
        <CollapsiblePanel/>
        <MainPanel />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

If anybody already overcame this problem, or if I have misunderstood anything please correct me :)
Thanks for the time.

EDIT:
I am using this App in my index.js:

````
import App from './app'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../public/css/MyStyle.css';
import '../public/css/nav.css';

  
  ReactDOM.render(
    App(),
    document.getElementById('root')
  );```
````

Comment: Where are you using the `App` elsewhere in the script?

Comment: Answer in edit in post :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `App()`, you're calling it as if it was a *normal function*, not as a React component. When React sees the call of `App`, it can't detect that it's being used as a functional component - it just thinks that it's a normal function. Use JSX syntax to call `App` instead:

```
ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('root') );
```

(you could also use `React.createElement`, but JSX syntax is much easier)